# How does Flyway deal with the fact that several dynos can try to run several migrations in parallel?

Tags: heroku, flyway

I am just wondering how Flyway deals with the fact that several dynos can try to run a database migration several times in a clustered environment such as Heroku thereby causing a conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Flyway uses locking in order to deal with this issue.

To quote the documentation:

> Can multiple nodes migrate in parallel? Yes! Flyway uses the locking
>   technology of your database to coordinate multiple nodes. This ensures
>   that even if even multiple instances of your application attempt to
>   migrate the database at the same time, it still works. Cluster
>   configurations are fully supported.

Answer (score 2):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823902/several-app-instances-trying-to-migrate-the-same-database-at-the-same-time) explains a bit more how the locking behaviour works. It appears to acquire a lock on the Flyway schema table: `select * from dbschema.schema_version for update` which might cause problems for longer running migrations as the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` setting might cause a timeout, at least in the case of MySQL.